# Docker Service - Push new image to one node

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-ucp

We are looking for ways we can do one box test in our production services which runs on docker swarm

Is there a way where one can push a later version of the image to one of the replica's in swarm for some time and roll it back ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only change an image for an entire Service, not a replica container in that service.

If you want to test an app, you would start a new Service on a different port or URL (if using a reverse proxy) and then tear it down later.

You could also use that method with a reverse proxy to do a blue/green/canary deployment.